# The intellij idea takes up a lot of Ram

Tags: javascript, java, performance, intellij-idea, ram

The intellij idea takes up a lot of RAM, is there a way we can reduce the program size?

Comment: Is this a problem? And how is this related to software development? If you have an issue with some vendors software you should typically contact that vendor and complain.

Comment: my computer is old so it can't handle large programs.

Comment: Why C# and HTML tags?

Comment: I used it to share the question. Sorry if it's irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to
C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.1 (your version)

edit idea64.exe.vmoptions

```yaml
-Xmx2015m -> -Xmx1024m (maximum memory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the heap of memory the compiler in the "Build, Execution, Deployment" tab in the preferences.

```
Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler | User local process heap size (...)
```

But you can search in preferences for "Mbyte" and see whatelse you can configure.